# Selenium doesn't close any browsers until ALL tests are complete

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing something like this (below) with multiple Test Classes but [ClassCleanup] is not called until ALL tests run.

Because of this each class starts up a browser and ALL of the browsers remain open until ALL of the tests are completed, and then they ALL close down.

Is this expected?
Could someone comment if their tests do the same thing?
Is there a way to force a browser to close when the test class is done?

```
[ClassCleanup]
    public static void ClassCleanup()
    {
        driver.Quit();
```

I dont know if this is just how Selenium is supposed to work, or if I have some sort of hanging resource that doesn't allow the browser to close until the end?

I cannot use [TestCleanup] because then I cannot have multiple tests in the same test class (as it will close before the 2nd test will run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an example that works :)
Simply replaced

```
[ClassCleanup]
```

with

```
[ClassCleanup(ClassCleanupBehavior.EndOfClass)]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `[TestInitialize]` as setUp and `[TestCleanup]` as Teardown of each test case.

In your code, it runs after class(all test cases)

So full code:

**Setup:**

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void InitializeTest() {
//your driver initilazation code
}
```

and, **Teardown:**

```
[TestCleanup]
public void Cleanup() {
driver.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahsum, I gave that a try and it didn't work how I needed it to.  This did actually close down the browser, so that was good.  However, this causes the Quit command to run after every test, so if there is more than one test in a class, the subsequent tests will all fail because the driver has quit. In other words, I really need the ClassCleanup tag to work correctly so it will only run 1 time per class (not after each test).